# Appium- Getting app configuration error while running the code

Tags: selenium, appium

FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest setUp
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: No app set; either start appium with --app or pass in an 'app' value in desired capabilities, or set androidPackage to launch pre-existing app on device) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 98 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'
System info: host: 'GOD23342', ip: '10.244.46.14', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_92'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:647)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:247)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:129)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:156)
    at Android.firsttest.setUp(firsttest.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:510)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:211)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:647)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:615)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:357)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:352)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:310)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:259)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1185)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1110)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1018)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package Android;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class firsttest {
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities().android();

        capabilities.setCapability("no", true);
        capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 100000);
        capabilities.setCapability("noReset", true);

        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Medfield9C8687DA");
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");

        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "4.4.4");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Venue7 3740 LTE");
        // capabilities.setCapability("app", application.getAbsolutePath());
        capabilities.setCapability("noRest", true);
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");

        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity",
                "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),
                capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void Sum() {
        driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button")).get(0).click();

        driver.findElement(By.name("2")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.name("+")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("5")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("=")).click();
        String result = driver.findElement(
                By.className("android.widget.EditText")).getText();
        System.out.println("Number sum result is : " + result);
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void End() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind people i figured out the solution....
Added the package name and it worked
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.calculator2");